# Is passing an email list by POST rather than GET possible?

Tags: gmail

I am using the following to create an on-the-fly live updating email list for interested users on my site:
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&tf=0&fs=1&to=email@address.com&cc=blah@blah.com,another@one.com&body=test%20email&shva=1

This works great for a few emails and has been the only solution I have found for mailing lists using gmail. Please let me kow if there is a better way to do this. Gmail seems to lack functionality to do this on it's own.

So the problem:
I now have close to 500 email addresses which gives me the beautiful error

Request-URI Too Large The requested URL /mail/... is too large to process.

For obvious reasons. I was wondering if there is a way (or one could be added) to support POST variables in addition to GET variables. I tried a few tests with no luck.
Please help me as many people count on it. Thanks!

p.s. it does not have to be pretty, just function correctly

Answer (score 1):

Gmail isn't designed to deal with recipient lists that long. You should look for a dedicated mailing list service - you could even use a private google groups group for it.

Remember, if you have a list that long, you'd better be prepared to deal with unsubscribe requests (unless you want your gmail account disabled :). A proper mailing list service will take care of this for you.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but it is because my body is very long. It looks gmail can only hanle about 800 chars in this approach. How can I send longer message? As attachment? How?